# Sort from a certain position in a String

Tags: python, sorting

Take a collection of these kinds of strings:

```
"foo: a message"
"bar: d message"
"bar: b message"
"foo: c message"
```

The two strings `foo:` and `bar:` are of the same length so I would like to start sorting from index of position `5` So my output would be...

```
"foo: a message"
"bar: b message"
"foo: c message"
"bar: d message"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a `key` function to slice each string; sorting then takes place using the values produced by the key.

```
sorted(inputlist, key=lambda s: s[5:])
```

Demo:

```
>>> inputlist = ['foo: a message', 'bar: d message', 'bar: b message', 'foo: c message']
>>> sorted(inputlist, key=lambda s: s[5:])
['foo: a message', 'bar: b message', 'foo: c message', 'bar: d message']
```

Quoting the [`sorted()` documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted):

> *key* specifies a function of one argument that is used to extract a comparison key from each list element: `key=str.lower`. The default value is `None` (compare the elements directly).

Comment: What exactly is key referring to? Is it some sort of keyword?

Comment: @Ogen `key` is an optional argument. [From the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted): "The optional arguments _cmp_, _key_, and _reverse_ have the same meaning as those for the `list.sort()` method (described in section [Mutable Sequence Types](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-mutable)). [...] _key_ specifies a function of one argument that is used to extract a comparison key from each list element: `key=str.lower`. The default value is `None` (compare the elements directly)."